# Was ist die korrekte Reihenfolge der Wörter in "Je... desto" Strukturen?

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

Welche Sätze sind korrekt?

1. Je älter man wird, desto weniger Energie und Neugier man hat.
2. Je älter man wird, desto weniger Energie und Neugier hat man.
3. Je älter man wird, desto weniger Energie und Neugier hat.

Danke.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, indeed, why?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Not I was the down, but I think some of the questions degrade the native speakers to a free translator service and they are not happy on it. Although maybe they are fighting this too vehemently. Homework, test questions shouldn't be asked in my opinion. Anybody can fill out a highest level language test on his/her first language, but it doesn't mean that they would do this happily in their free time.

Comment: @peterh Thank you for some explanation. The way I wrote it indeed looks as if they were some test questions, but no, I'm writing an essay in German and came across a problem which version of the expression I should choose. I can assure you that the first thing I do is look it up in dictionaries and browse online, however, when I encounter a problem I don't know how to handle or want some higher level clarification, I'd think natives on this site would be best to turn to. It's only my second question here and both haven't been received enthusiastically, so I must learn how to word them better.

Comment: Keine der Sätze sind inhaltlich korrekt. ;-) No, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Theta   Yes, somehow I sensed that this is not the usual "please do my homework" question, and that it is rather driven by the interest of understanding structures...

Comment: @Rudy  You are right about this, and I included an example sentence refering to your remark in my answer below. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> <s>Je älter man wird, desto weniger Energie und Neugier man hat.</s>

This sentence could have come from Yoda’s mouth.

> Je älter man wird, desto weniger Energie und Neugier hat man.

This sentence is correct. See [this](https://deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/vergleichssaetze-je-desto/) page for more information.

> <s>Je älter man wird, desto weniger Energie und Neugier hat.</s>

In this sentence the subject is missing: it’s wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it helps to give more examples of correctly built sentences of this kind. [Vielleicht hilft es, einige Beispiele wohlgeformter Sätze dieser Art anzuführen.]

> Je mehr Kuchen man ißt, desto weniger bleibt auf dem Teller.
>
> Je öfter man trainiert, desto besser wird man.
>
> Je freundlicher du auftrittst, desto mehr Erfolg wirst du haben.
>
> Je länger Trump regiert, desto absurder wird die politische Lage in den USA.
>
> Je mehr Beispiele man sieht, desto klarer wird das Grundprinzip.
>
> Je älter man wird, desto schneller kann man Zusammenhänge begreifen, denn neue Informationen können an ein immer reicher werdendes Synapsen-Netz anschließen.

And here is a special case:

> Je grüner das Gras, desto glücklicher die Kuh.

Note that here there is no verb at all. Verbs (here: *sein*) are left out (you can call this an *ellipsis*) as they are somehow self-evident in this sentence. This is a well-established way to use je-desto-sentences in German.